# При поиске определенного адреса в полигоне через АПИ яндекс карт находится 10 объектов вместо одного

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Всем доброго времени суток, прошу помощи!
Есть скрипт который через АПИ яндекс карт ищет в полигоне введенный адрес, но при определенном адресе находятся 10 объектов вместо одного, не могу разобраться почему.

```
var addr = 'Россия, Саратов, 7-я Нагорная улица, 6';
var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [51.53922,46.05327], zoom: 19
    }),
    myPolygon = new ymaps.Polygon([ [
                [ 51.4814, 45.8818 ],
                [ 51.4770, 45.8864 ],
                [ 51.4796, 45.8928 ],
                [ 51.4777, 45.8957 ],
                [ 51.4784, 45.9034 ],
                [ 51.4755, 45.9047 ],
                [ 51.4726, 45.9037 ],
                [ 51.4673, 45.9068 ],
                [ 51.4589, 45.9120 ],
                [ 51.4502, 45.9036 ],
                [ 51.4455, 45.9188 ],
                [ 51.4446, 45.9256 ],
                [ 51.4457, 45.9352 ],
                [ 51.4595, 45.9326 ],
                [ 51.4638, 45.9381 ],
                [ 51.4689, 45.9316 ],
                [ 51.4756, 45.9335 ],
                [ 51.4888, 45.9687 ],
                [ 51.4998, 45.9764 ],
                [ 51.5075, 45.9924 ],
                [ 51.5147, 46.0148 ],
                [ 51.5213, 46.0390 ],
                [ 51.5270, 46.0643 ],
                [ 51.5303, 46.0735 ],
                [ 51.5340, 46.0779 ],
                [ 51.5426, 46.0824 ],
                [ 51.5443, 46.0791 ],
                [ 51.5457, 46.0776 ],
                [ 51.5471, 46.0768 ],
                [ 51.5488, 46.0756 ],
                [ 51.5517, 46.0777 ],
                [ 51.5531, 46.0763 ],
                [ 51.5556, 46.0782 ],
                [ 51.5571, 46.0754 ],
                [ 51.5582, 46.0723 ],
                [ 51.5582, 46.0679 ],
                [ 51.5585, 46.0538 ],
                [ 51.5588, 46.0508 ],
                [ 51.5588, 46.0505 ],
                [ 51.5587, 46.0476 ],
                [ 51.5576, 46.0441 ],
                [ 51.5563, 46.0418 ],
                [ 51.5560, 46.0405 ],
                [ 51.5575, 46.0343 ],
                [ 51.5574, 46.0319 ],
                [ 51.5578, 46.0313 ],
                [ 51.5583, 46.0316 ],
                [ 51.5591, 46.0328 ],
                [ 51.5610, 46.0331 ],
                [ 51.5621, 46.0326 ],
                [ 51.5685, 46.0349 ],
                [ 51.5698, 46.0304 ],
                [ 51.5706, 46.0276 ],
                [ 51.5740, 46.0277 ],
                [ 51.5762, 46.0203 ],
                [ 51.5778, 46.0126 ],
                [ 51.5709, 46.0084 ],
                [ 51.5719, 46.0045 ],
                [ 51.5696, 46.0021 ],
                [ 51.5626, 45.9853 ],
                [ 51.5602, 45.9728 ],
                [ 51.5541, 45.9814 ],
                [ 51.5499, 45.9919 ],
                [ 51.5476, 45.9835 ],
                [ 51.5424, 45.9774 ],
                [ 51.5530, 45.9623 ],
                [ 51.5509, 45.9536 ],
                [ 51.5421, 45.9573 ],
                [ 51.5419, 45.9534 ],
                [ 51.5392, 45.9446 ],
                [ 51.5367, 45.9454 ],
                [ 51.5353, 45.9499 ],
                [ 51.5323, 45.9454 ],
                [ 51.5251, 45.9472 ],
                [ 51.5211, 45.9362 ],
                [ 51.5187, 45.9149 ],
                [ 51.5154, 45.8991 ],
                [ 51.5028, 45.8952 ],
                [ 51.4921, 45.8849 ],
                [ 51.4814, 45.8818 ]            
    ] ]);
myMap.geoObjects.add(myPolygon);
var result = ymaps.geoQuery(ymaps.geocode(addr)).searchInside(myPolygon);
result.then(function () {
    var price = 0;//по умолчанию адрес внутри зоны бесплатной доставки
    if(result.getLength() != 1){//адрес доставки вне бесплатной зоны
        price = 100;
    }
});
```

Comment: Я только не понял условие "if(result.getLength() != 1){//адрес доставки вне бесплатной зоны" Почему если больше одного результата, то это автоматически значит, что адрес вне бесплатной зоны?)

Answer (score 1):

Не гарантируется, что всегда будет находиться только один адрес. Но первый найденный адрес будет самым точным. Так что вы можете запрашивать только первый результат.
    `ymaps.geocode(addr,{results: 1})`
http://jsfiddle.net/914f6omn/

Либо забирать его так уже после фильтрации:
`result.get(0)`
 https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/GeoQueryResult-docpage/#method_detail__get